# Fiware Upload Image

Tags: fiware, json-ld, fiware-orion, fiware-cygnus

I want to know how to use [NSGI-LD](https://ngsi-ld-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to upload an image even though these static files are not stored in Orion Context Broker or Mongo. I want to know if there is a way to configure the NSGI-LD to forward the images to AWS S3 Buck or another location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you correctly identified, binary files are not a good candidate for context data, and should not be held directly within a context broker. The usual paradigm would be as follows:

Imagine you have a number plate reader library linked to [Kurento](https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-media-server) and wish to store the images of vehicles as they pass. In this case the **event** from the media stream should cause two separate actions:

- Upload the raw image to a storage server
- Upsert the context data to the context broker **including** an attribute holding the URI of the stored image.

Doing things this way means you can confirm that the image is safely stored, and then send the following:

```json
{
    "vehicle_registration_number": {
        "type": "Property",
        "value": "X123RPD"
    },
    "image_download": {
        "type": "Property",
        "value": "http://example.com/url/to/image"
    }
}
```

The alternative would be to simply include some link back to the source file somehow as metadata:

```json
{
    "vehicle_registration_number": {
        "type": "Property",
        "value": "X123RPD",
        "origin": {
            "type": "Property",
            "value": "file://localimage"
        }
    }
}
```

Then if you have a registration on `vehicle_registration_number` which somehow links back to the server with the original file, it could upload the image **after** the context broker has been updated (and then do another upsert)

Option one is simpler. Option two would make more sense if the registration is narrower. For example, *only upload images of VRNs for cars whose `speed` attribute is  greater than 70 km/h*.

Ontologically you could say that **Device** has a relationship to a **Photograph** which would mean that **Device** could have an additional `latestRecord` attribute:

```json
{
    "latestRecord": {
        "type": "Relationship",
        "object": "urn:ngsi-ld:CatalogueRecordDCAT-AP:0001"
    },
}
```

And and create a separate entity holding the details of the **Photograph itself** using a standard data model such as  [CatalogueRecordDCAT-AP](https://github.com/smart-data-models/dataModel.DCAT-AP/blob/master/CatalogueRecordDCAT-AP) which is defined [here](https://joinup.ec.europa.eu/sites/default/files/distribution/access_url/2020-06/e4823478-4458-4546-9a85-3609867ad089/DCAT_AP_2.0.1.pdf). Attributes such as `source` and `sourceMetadata` help define the location of the raw file.

```json
{  
  "id": "urn:ngsi-ld:CatalogueRecordDCAT-AP:0001",  
  "type": "CatalogueRecordDCAT-AP",  
  "dateCreated": "2020-11-02T21:25:54Z",  
  "dateModified": "2021-07-02T18:37:55Z",    
  "description": "Speeding Ticket",  
  "dataProvider": "European open data portal",   
  "location": {  
    "type": "Point",  
    "coordinates": [  
      36.633152,  
      -85.183315  
    ]  
  },  
  "address": {  
    "streetAddress": "2, rue Mercier",  
    "addressLocality": "Luxembourg",  
    "addressRegion": "Luxembourg",  
    "addressCountry": "Luxembourg",  
    "postalCode": "2985",  
    "postOfficeBoxNumber": ""  
  },  
  "areaServed": "European Union and beyond",  
  "primaryTopic": "Public administration",  
  "modificationDate": "2021-07-02T18:37:55Z",  
  "applicationProfile": "DCAT Application profile for data portals in Europe",  
  "changeType": "First version",  
  "source": "http://example.com/url/to/image"
  "sourceMetadata": {"type" :"jpeg", "height" : 100, "width": 100},    
  "@context": [  
    "https://smartdatamodels.org/context.jsonld"  
  ]  
}
```